# Checking dice roll combinations in C

Tags: c

I try to code a little dice game in C. I am a beginner in C and still have to learn a lot. The user inserts the numbers of 5 dices. The program puts every number into an array and then prints out one of 4 cases:

1. Grand = same number on all 5 dices
2. Poker = same number on 4 dices
3. Full House = 3 equal and 2 equal numbers
4. Lose = No Grand, Poker or Full House

I just could write an if-statement-block that checks every possible combination and then prints the right case into the console. But that would take me quite a while. So I wanted to ask if there is an easier way to achieve that.

I coded the Grand and Lose so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int dices[5];

    printf("Program Dice game \n\n");

    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("dice %i: ", i+1);
        scanf("%i", &dices[i]);
    }

    printf("dice \t");
    printf("1 \t");
    printf("2 \t");
    printf("3 \t");
    printf("4 \t");
    printf("5 \n");
    printf("number \t");

    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%i \t", dices[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    if(dices[0] == dices[1] && dices[0] == dices[2] 
        && dices[0] == dices[3] && dices[0] == dices[4]) {
        printf("Win! Grand!");
    } else {
        printf("Lose!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The plural of _die_ is _dice_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to sort your dice array. This way, you'll have a lot fewer comparaisons to do. here's an exemple:

```
int cmp_func (const void *a, const void *b)
{
   return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

int main() {

    int dice[5] = {2, 3, 2, 3, 3}; //arbitrary dice combination

    qsort(dice, 5, sizeof(int), cmp_func);

    if (dice[0] == dice[4])
    {
        printf("Grand\n");
    }
    else if (dice[1] == dice[4] || dice[0] == dice[3])
    {
        printf("Poker\n");
    }
    else if ((dice[0] == dice[2] && dice[3] == dice[4]) || (dice[0] == dice[1] && dice[2] == dice[4]))
    {
        printf("Full House\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Lose\n");
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Once your dice are sorted, if the first one is equal to the last one, you can assume they're all equals. If the first one is equal to the fouth one OR the second one is equal to the last one, you can assume you have 4 same dice, etc...

Note that if the initial order of your dice array matters, you'll have to duplicate it and use the other array to sort / test.